# google api is installed but I am not create map app in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I Want to create a map app in android studio, but I can't.
In my Android-sdk, Google-API is installed but I don't create map app in android studio.
How to create it?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple..first you have to register your project in https://console.developers.google.com/project ,i prefer switching to older version , then you need to generate the api key in the API section also you will have t o enable Google API V2 . After generating the api key you only need to use tha api key in your manifest file

```
    <meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="Your Api key" />
```

Then just create a simple activity and insert these command

```
      SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

I hope it helps